# unusual "distance" in complex space

Tags: complex-numbers, metric-spaces

I've encountered a notion of distance (their usage) in the field of ecology that raises an eyebrow, and would like to know if it's used elsewhere (if it makes any sense at all).

If you diagonalize a real symmetric $nxn$ matrix and then scale each eigenvector by the square root of its associated eigenvalue (see [PCoA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling#Classical_multidimensional_scaling)), you may have earned yourself an orthogonal basis for a complex space. Can you get away with defining a (non-metric) distance, $d_{ij}$, between points $z_i = \{a_{ik} + b_{ik}i\}_{k\in n}$ that satisfies:

$$
d_{ij}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ik} - a_{jk})^2 - (b_{ik}-b_{jk})^2
$$

Yes, minus. If you can, and it's a thing, what's it called?

---

Edit: Thanks, Servaes. Fixed.

Comment: What does the $j$ in the subscript $d_{ij}^2$ do?

Comment: $z_i$ denotes a set of $n$ complex numbers?

Comment: This looks a bit like a [spacetime interval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval). I'd be surprised to find an application in ecology, of all fields. But of course, you can define anything you want as long as the definition isn't self-contradictory, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the mention of PCoA has to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ ... sorry, was attempting to be concise.

Comment: @Rahul Wanted to explain in some way the reason for the scaling by eigenvalue roots, which is Step 4 at the link. Was definitely not expecting an answer to involve "spacetime" but that's the kind of help I'm looking for. Also, maybe it is contradictory in some way?